# How to differentiate text and change align accordingly

Tags: c#, windows, form-control

I have a requirement, I have a textfield which I'm fetching the data from database. It may be in Arabic or in English. I want to differentiate it dynamically and change alignment accordingly. ie, if the text is in Arabic it should be from right to left else left to right.

Comment: If text contains RTL mark then Windows does it for you. Otherwise you may simply check for characters (don't forget System.Char represents a code-unit, not a code-point) in [Unicode Arabic Code block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block))

Comment: Maybe you can add column-flag in DB for RTL text.

Comment: It the text does not contain the RTL mark then Windows *still* does it for you.  However, the going gets tough if the text is mixed with, say, both Arabic glyphs and Western punctuation or digits.  This is really rather best solved in the program that adds the dbase content since it is the one that (should) know the actual meaning of the text.

Comment: @Hans Windows will correctly **append text** on the left (instead of the right) and keep right characters order but it won't make it **right aligned** (as it should be for a RTL input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can said that the text is in arabic, if count of arabic characters is more than count of english characters.

You can determine it using [character classes in regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx)

```
    public bool IsArabic(this string input)
    {
        var isArabic = Regex.Matches(input, "\\p{IsArabic}");
        var isLatin = Regex.Matches(input, "\\p{IsBasicLatin}");

        if (isArabic == null)
            return false;

        if (isLatin == null)
            return true; //suggest that there is no another character types

        if (isArabic.Count > isLatin.Count)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Nice catch for named classes (much more readable than hard-coded range) but counting characters is really over-engineering and arbitrary. IMO if there is ONE Arabic character (or another RTL alphabet) then it's Arabic and it should be RTL. BTW IsBasicLatin (from \u0000 to \u007f) includes also many common _symbols_ and _numbers_ (often used also in Arabic text instead of Arabic-Indic digits).

Answer (score 1):

If text contains [RTL mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) then Windows does it for you.

Otherwise you may simply check for characters (don't forget `System.Char` represents a code-unit, not a code-point but in this case it's not an issue) in [Unicode Arabic Code block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)):

```
public bool IsArabic(string text)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(text, "[\u06000-\u06FF]")
}
```